# What? Locked out of Apple Store for uploads, and weird unicode characters have taken over my Apple Account

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect, itunes-store

A first for me. I'm locked out of uploads to the Apple store (using testflight). My account info seems to have all been turned into unicode!  Ok, digging into all, wondering if someone has had this "Lock Out" thing happen to them. Thanks. At the moment I can't UL anything to Apple. I should have 100% access to all roles. Weird!

[image]

Comment: [The iTunes Store has been down since 5:00 AM EDT today](https://www.apple.com/support/systemstatus/). That's probably why.

Answer (score 2):

Apple has widespread service issues today.  You can follow along with these sites.

Service Status: https://www.apple.com/support/systemstatus/

Mac Rumors: http://www.macrumors.com/2015/03/11/app-store-itunes-connect-down-march/

Comment: Thanks, wow, I was freaking out. It had to be the info.pList. It had to be. Of course had nothing to do with that.